# Is there a way to stop onTouchEvent being called in Android

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to know if there a way to stop `onTouchEvent` from being called in Android? In my project, I subclass `imageView` and override the `onTouchEvent` to implement some effect, but in some other places, when I use this class, I don't want `onTouchEvent` to be called. I have tried the property such as `setEnable()` and `setClickable()`, both of them do not work. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: try returning false from onTouchEvent method

Comment: What I really want to know is, is there a way to stop put this imageview in the touch responder chain?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something similar

```
public class MyImageview  extends ImageView{

    private boolean isTouchEnable;

    public MyImageview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if(isTouchEnable){
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}

    public boolean isTouchEnable() {
        return isTouchEnable;
    }

    public void setTouchEnable(boolean isTouchEnable) {
        this.isTouchEnable = isTouchEnable;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do I have to maintain a isTouchEnable property? Can I use android's setClickable or setEnable?

Comment: MyImageview mMyImageview= new MyImageview(); If you want to disable touch set mMyImageview.setTouchEnable(false);

Comment: I know this works, can you explain what setClickable(false) and setEnable(false) means? Do these two function affect the pass of touchevent?

Comment: I havent checked that.You can do further checking with isEnabled() and 
isClickable()